# Potty a 2 year old, who uses the potty in day care, and not at home

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My 2 year old daughter, has been potty training with pull up for the past 3 months. So far at day care she uses the potty perfectly, with no accident. At home she doesn't want to go at all we ask her she says no, accident all the time. And just refuses to use the potty at home.

Comment: What is your setup like at home? Is it similar to the one at school? Have you talked to her teachers to see what they do there?

Answer (score 2):

I think that possibly that the *other children* are the motivation that is missing at home.

She doesn't want to be a big girl at home. Home is where she is very happy being your baby.

At school she has peers and wants to be one of the big kids. Toddler peer pressure.

If it was my child, I'd just take the pressure off at home. Two is young to be trained. This summer (if your next season is summer where you live), let her be outside in underwear (no diaper) and let her feel wet. I think if you put a potty in your yard, she'll choose the potty over wet pants. If she has wet pants, she waits for 10 minutes or so for a change -- you decide the time. If you do not have a yard, I would not put any pressure on at all. She will come around.

The last thing we want is to make using a diaper, 'bad'. This is a natural part of development and rushing it will not make things better -- it may in truth make it last longer because little children have few choices and opportunities to assert themselves.

Also btw, this is the time to start allowing choices and using 'choosing' language. It will help in every area of daily life -- from potty training to discipline to school work..

Comment: So much this. Day cares like to potty train early. When this happened with our daughter, we explicitly told the day care that they were welcome to try, but we would not potty trains her at home, instead we kept her in diapers at home until she started going to the toilet (with an insert seat) proper. Admittedly I wasn't keen on cleaning potties, so that suited me just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Potty training if definitely tough but what helped with my youngest (out of 4) was a sticker chart I let him pick out stickers put the potty seat in the living right by the potty sticker chart and he was excited the more the poster board got filled up. After the poster board was full he was running to start running upstairs to the bathroom. Good luck